# Creating a virtual host using webmin loads default site

Tags: apache, virtualhost, webmin

So I'm trying to set up a rackspace cloud server to host multiple sites (not servers) with a single IP. I installed Virtualmin/Webmin on an Ubuntu 12.04 LTS server. I created the directory /var/www/sites/testsite. Then I created a virtual host under Webmin->Servers->Apache Webserver with the following settings:

```
Address: Any
Port: 80
Document Root: /var/www/sites/testsite
Server Name: testsite.com
```

Then, to test it, I edited the hosts file on my local machine and added

```
[my.server.ip.address] testsite.com
```

Then went to testsite.com in my browser and problem is it's loading the default site (at /var/www) instead of the virtual one I just created (I verfied this by adding different index.html files in /var/www and /var/www/sites/testsite).

Here are the directives webmin created in /etc/apache2/sites-available/webmin.1372454178.conf

```
DocumentRoot /var/www/sites/testsite
<Directory "/var/www/sites/testsite">
allow from all
Options +Indexes
</Directory>
ServerName testsite.com
ServerAlias www.testsite.com
```

Comment: Is the answer right? If so it should be accepted. Thanks!

Comment: It would be nice if it was marked as correct ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i fixed this by adding directive
ServerAlias domain.tld *.domain.tld

You can find this for setup under Apache -> Your Virtual Domain settings -> Networking and Addresses -> Alternate virtual server names FIELD.

domain.tld
*.domain.tld

Answer (score 1):

It our case we have forget to add server name initially and then webmin virtual host edit/delete, it does not updated Directive so Server Name was missing in it.. After adding Server name and Restarting apache it has started working perfectly..

Servers -> Apache Webserver: Select your virtual Server -> Edit Directives

```
Server Name: testsite.com
```

Others -> Command Shell

```
service apache2 restart
```

Open your web address in browser.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that mixing 'Any' with a specific port doesn't play nicely for some reason.

Try updating the vhost settings to:

```
Address: Any
Port: Any
Document Root: /var/www/sites/testsite
Server Name: testsite.com
```

When doing so, ensure that you empty any boxes that were filled in as part of you selecting a specific port.

Also, just as a side note, get used to setting your sites to not allow directory indexing, unless of course specifically required.

So in the Actual Directives Set:

```
Options -Indexes
```

This will stop people digging around in your site. If of course you need to allow someone to view a directory, you can add permission to do so on a folder by folder basis using .htaccess